# Magento Configurable Product Import With Simple Products

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a problem with Magento 1.9 built in import/export tool.
What I have done is:

1) I created attributes (4 of them).

2) Created attribute set.

3) Created configurable product and added some simple products to that
    configurable product.

4) Exported this product using Data Flow Profiles leaving all settings at default.

5) Modified the export file by adding multiple extra options and saved it as MS-DOS csv file.

6) Imported using Data Flow Profiles Import all products option again leaving everything at default except I have changed import number of rows value to a bigger value.

After a close examination I see that new simple products have been added to Magento store, but they are not associated with my configurable product. 
I have tried to move the line that imports the configurable product to the bottom of the csv file, but that did not help.

Has anyone else come across this problem and how did you tackle it?

Comment: I heard the default dataflow profiles doesn't support configurable/simple product associations. Try clicking the "Import" button on the Import/Export tab, try exporting your data like this, and try importing/exporting your data through there instead of the dataflow profiles.

Comment: @Iqbal Khan I have done it the other way, I have added all the simple products and had their sku starting with same sequence as configurable product, then went into my magento management panel, opened configurable product>associated products and at the bottom table at the top left there is a drop down with yes/no options, I selected no and all my products where then listed, all I had to do is select them and you can do that by clicking one checkbox above the dropdown mentioned previously. Thats it, job done :)